# access token google cloud permission denied for vertex ai

Tags: php, google-api, access-token, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Why when I run the post url vertex ai command using the access token that I print from the cloud shell terminal can be run, while when using the access token from the coding below an error appears with message access token denied

```
$app->get("/m_article/getToken", function ($request, $response) {
require __DIR__ . '../../vendor/autoload.php';

$keyFilePath = 'my-cloud.json';

$keyFile = json_decode(file_get_contents($keyFilePath), true);

// Set up the Google API client
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($keyFile);

// Set the scope for the access token (e.g., Cloud Storage)
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']);

// Get the access token
$accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();

return successResponse($response, $accessToken);
```

});

[access denied in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQYKk.png)

how to Can run Vertex AI URL using access token from my code

Comment: 1) Always show the exact error message. 2) Show the code or command that generates the error. 3) Which IAM roles are assigned to the service account? Edit your post with the details.